# How to restore missing Documentum folder (UCF) under user profile folder?

Tags: documentum, webtop

When a user logs into documentum is able to browse and query for documents, but once it hits the display button the doc viewers just load a blank line. When going to menu "Tools > Preferences" I got a message saying my browser doesn't support Java (It is internet explorer 11)

I noticed that under the profile folder for the user (C:\Windows\Users[user]) she's missing a "Documentum" folder which it should have the UCF folder and most likely is the cause of the issue of not displaying the documents through viewONe

How can I restore this folder or get the viewOne installed on user's browser ?

The issue seems to be that IE11 is not loading Java Applets all

Webtop version: 6.7

**Update (solved):**
After posting other question here on SO and being redirected to SU site, I got to fix the issue by uninstalling al JRE and installing only version 1.7.45 for 32bits (x86), I did tried a lot of things before doing the uninstall/install more details in the SU question I posted https://superuser.com/questions/1468472/java-jre-1-7-45-not-working-internet-explorer-11-and-webtop-6-7-applets?noredirect=1#comment2215590_1468472

Comment: Yes that is what I wrote in the answer for the original question - recent browsers does not support Java applets at all. Try using HTTP transfer mechanism instead of UCF as described in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Webtop 6.0 is quite old and it requires UCF Java applet installed in the browser so you should use also an old version of the browser where Java applets are still supported (none of current browsers support Java applets). Then the *Documentum* folder will be created automatically by the applet.

Or you can enable HTTP transfer mode instead of UCF by changing default mechanism this way:

```
<default-mechanism>http</default-mechanism>
```

... in the *webtop/wdk/app.xml* file.

But if you have some custom integration of viewOne directly into the Webtop then the problem will be in that custom integration and then you should consult it with the developer who did it or provide us more information about that (view action configuration, browser console log, ...).

**Update:** You can try to install the UCF on the client system using this command:

```
java -cp ucfinit.jar com.documentum.ucf.client.install.TestInstall "http://my-server.with.webtop:8080/webtop" "/wdk/contentXfer/ucf.installer.config.xml"
```

Library *ucfinit.jar* can be downloaded from Webtop using this relative path: *webtop/wdk/system/ucfinit.jar*

Comment: It turns out it was some sort of JRE version conflict, I ended up uninstalling all the JRE versions (1.7.17 x86,x64 and 1.7.45 x86,x64) and then installing the one version that was working on a diff machine (1.7.45 x86) and that alongside some scurity settings fix the issue more details here: https://superuser.com/questions/1468472/java-jre-1-7-45-not-working-internet-explorer-11-and-webtop-6-7-applets?noredirect=1#comment2215590_1468472 

Still thanks for your answer